# Accessing properties of a spritebuilder object outside of its class in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, inheritance, properties, spritebuilder

I'm very confused on how Spritebuilder links in with Xcode.

I'm currently using CCBloader to "initialize"(?) my custom classes which I have created in Spritebuilder, but I cannot access the properties which I have defined.

In my spritebuilder, I have a CCNode called ContentPane which has these nested CCNodes called _rockPath1 and _rockPath2, both of those contain a .png file that looks like rocks.

_rockPath1 and _rockPath2 are both owner variables.

Here is what ContentPane looks like:
The header file:

```
@interface ContentPane : CCNode

@property (nonatomic, assign) CCNode * _rockPath1;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CCNode * _rockPath2;

@end
```

The .m file:

```
@implementation ContentPane{
}
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CCLOG(@"ContentPane created");
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

And here is where I initialize the contentPane inside a file called Gameplay.m:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {

    CCNode* pane = [CCBReader load: @"ContentPane"];
    [self addChild:pane];

    //HERE I TRY TO ACCESS THE PROPERTY _ROCKPATH1
    pane._rockPath1.position = ccp(50,50);

}
```

It gives me the error "Property _rockPath1 not found on object of type CCNode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because as far as the compiler knows, `pane` is just a `CCNode` object, and `CCNode` does not have the property `_rockPath1`.

You need to explicitly declare `pane` as the type you expect it to be, which in this case is `ContentPane`, and then cast the object returned by `+[CCBReader load:]` to that type:

```
- (void)didLoadFromCCB 
{
    ContentPane *pane = (ContentPane *)[CCBReader load: @"ContentPane"];
    [self addChild:pane];

    pane._rockPath1.position = ccp(50,50);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it haha.

However, the CCBReader returns a CCNode object, so it gives me a warning. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: Did you include the `(ContentPane *)` part, right after the equals sign? That should silence that warning because you are casting it from a `CCNode` to a `ContentPane`.